# Duplicate searching script does not detect multiple values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to customize and re-write the code of duplicate finder that is provided by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates). My code is copied below. It's not final version yet but at this stage it should already work; I have no idea why is does not, unfortunately.

**tablicaLinkow** is an array containing all the values of active range,
**tablicaNowa** is an array where the non-duplicates sholuld be stored

How I wanted it to work is that 'tablicaLinkow' is array of values gathered from 2nd column of all the active rows (thus it's one-dimensional array). Script gets one value from 'tablicaLinkow' and searches for it in the 'tablicaNowa'. If it is present, script logs *duplicate*. If it is not, script puts it into the 'tablicaNowa' and logs that it is *not a duplicte*.

For some reason, script does not recognize duplicates; always logs that a value is not a duplicate despite it is; example log is also below.

Thanks for help!

```
function sprawdzWielokrotne3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var aktZas = ss.getActiveRange();

  var kolUwag = 9,                                     //Nevermind
      kolSpra = 2,                                     //Column that is to be checked
      aktRzad = aktZas.getRowIndex(),                  //First row of the active range
      aktWysk = aktZas.getHeight(),                    //Amount of active rows
      calSzer = sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns();  //Nevermind

  //Checks if user chose more than one row
  if (aktWysk > 1){
    //Gets values of 2nd column of all the active rows
    var tablicaLinkow = sheet.getRange(aktRzad, kolSpra, aktWysk).getValues();
    //Array where the non-duplicates are to be put
    var tablicaNowa = new Array();

    for (var i in tablicaLinkow){
      var duplo = false;
      for (var j in tablicaNowa){
        if (tablicaLinkow[i] == tablicaNowa[j]){
          duplo = true;
        }
      }
      if (duplo == false){
        Logger.log(tablicaLinkow[i] + ' not a duplicate');
        tablicaNowa.push(tablicaLinkow[i]);        
      } else {
        Logger.log(tablicaLinkow[i] + ' duplicate');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example log

```
[13-07-22 17:36:19:145 CEST] 3199894 not a duplicate
[13-07-22 17:36:19:145 CEST] 3199894 not a duplicate
[13-07-22 17:36:19:146 CEST] 3199894 not a duplicate
[13-07-22 17:36:19:146 CEST] 2417512 not a duplicate
[13-07-22 17:36:19:146 CEST] 2417512 not a duplicate
[13-07-22 17:36:19:147 CEST] 199894  not a duplicate
[13-07-22 17:36:19:147 CEST] 2342261 not a duplicate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say *"tablicaLinkow' is array of values gathered from 2nd column of all the active rows (thus it's one-dimensional array)"* this is not true and causes your script to fail.

The array returned by `getValues()` are ALWAYS 2D arrays, **even if the range is only one item width.**

Change your code to take this into account and it will probably work as you expect

`tablicaLinkow[i]`  should be replaced by `tablicaLinkow[i][0]`

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. Now, after I had read your explanation I see in the documentation that the array returned by getValues() is two-dimensional. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is a better choice.